# How would I test the number of matches that the RSpec matcher have_content finds on a page?

Tags: rspec

I am basically trying get the functionality for the "has_content?" or "should have_content" matcher that the option :count provides for the has_css? matcher.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like thats **all('a').length**

Here is several examples:

```
describe 'my awesome page' do
  before :each do
    visit root_path
  end

  # css just for querying DOM
  it 'number of titles should be huge' do
    page.all(:css,'h2.awesome_header').length.should have_at_least(3).items
  end
  it 'has exactly 4 div elements' do
    page.all(:css,'div.awesome_class').length.should == 4
  end

  # For querying content you can try :xpath instead :css. 
  it 'has paragraps with text' do
    page.all(:xpath, '//div[contains(., "t")]').length.should == 9
  end
end
```

**Update:**

I find more elegant way to do this.
Check documentation here: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders:all
here is working example

```
page.all(:css, 'p', :text => /.*wellcome.*/).length.should == 2
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  Could you write me an example test with this syntax?

Comment: These are really great examples, however I really want to find the number of times a string occurs on a rendered page, without knowing anything about where in the DOM it may or may not exist. I going to vote up your answer because it's great information, but I'm not going to mark it as "the answer" because it doesn't really give me a way to do what I am trying to do.  Thanks a Bunch :)

Comment: you can use some regexp against - **page.text**

Comment: Yes, that is just the sort of thing I was thinking of trying. Thanks :)